# Adding line type to legend in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

How do I make the line types used by geom_hline or geom_abline show up in the legend of a ggplot plot?

For example:

```
require (ggplot2)

# some data
dummy <- data.frame (category1 =  rep (1:5, 8), category2 = rep (1:4, each = 10), 
    category3 = rep (factor (1:2), 2), expected = 10 ^ rep (4:7, each = 10),
    value = 10 ^rnorm(40, 5))

# faceted plot
baseplot <-ggplot (dummy ) +
    geom_point (aes (category1, value, color = category3))+
    scale_y_log10 () + 
    facet_wrap (~category2)

# add a dotted line for expected value
p1 <-baseplot + geom_hline ( aes ( yintercept = expected), linetype = 2)
```

I tried a couple approaches to making the dotted line show up in the legend, but they give me the same thing as p1

```
p1a < -p1+scale_linetype_discrete (labels = "expected")+
    guides ( linetype= guide_legend ("", labels ="expected"))
p1b <- baseplot + geom_hline (aes (yintercept = expected, linetype = "expected")) +
    scale_linetype_manual (labels= "expected", values = 2)
p1a
p1b
```

How about multiple lines/line types?

Let's say I also wanted to plot groupwise and overall geometric means

```
require (reshape)
require (plyr)

# calculate geometric means, keep them in their own data frame
geometric_mean <- function (x)  exp ( mean (log (x)))
dummy $GM_overall <- geometric_mean (dummy $value)
extra <- ddply(dummy, c( "GM_overall", "expected","category2"), summarize,
    GM_group = geometric_mean (value))
extra_long <- melt (GM_group_long, id.vars = "category2")
```

I expected this approach to show linetype in the legend based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13254441/add-a-horizontal-line-to-plot-and-legend-in-ggplot2?rq=1), but no such luck

```
p2=baseplot + geom_hline ( aes ( yintercept = value , linetype = variable), extra)
p2
```

Here's another case where I would want to do something similar with abline

It would be nice to be able to label the line as 1:1

```
dummy$value2 <- dummy $value * runif(40, 0.5, 2)
ggplot (dummy)+coord_fixed() +    
    geom_point (aes (value, value2, color = category3))+
    geom_abline (yintercept =0, slope =1)
```

I'm using R 3.0.0, ggplot 0.9.3.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You run through several examples, but this simple case should get you most of the way there:

```
dummy <- data.frame (category1 =  rep (1:5, 8), category2 = rep (1:4, each = 10), 
    category3 = rep (factor (1:2), 2), expected = 10 ^ rep (4:7, each = 10),
    value = 10 ^rnorm(40, 5))

# faceted plot
baseplot <- ggplot(dummy) +
    geom_point(aes(category1, value, color = category3))+
    scale_y_log10() + 
    facet_wrap(~category2)

# add a dotted line for expected value
baseplot + geom_hline(aes(yintercept = expected,linetype = "expected"),show_guide = TRUE)
```

The key in most cases, I think, is adding `show_guide = TRUE`. It is `FALSE` by default for this geom, which may or may not be intuitive. (I can see the rationale.)

Note how, in this "one line type" case, I "tricked" ggplot into creating a legend by *mapping* linetype to the character "expected", which causes a new column to be created behind the scenes. Multiple line types should work as expected with the usual methods of creating columns and mapping them to linetype.

Comment: Thanks! For completeness' sake: adding 'guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype=0)))' makes the legend for color appear as points without lines, which is more appropriate for this case.