# How to add a line to a continuous color legend but not the plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to add a line *just* to a continuous gradient legend? I was unable to find any examples of this using ggplot2.

For example, how could I add a red horizontal line to only the legend at say, 1.7?

```
library(ggplot2)
x <- seq(1:1000)
y <-rnorm(1000,0,1)
df <- data.frame(x,y)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, color = y)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

Like this:

[image]

It might not make a lot of sense as to why I'd like that. For more context, I'm hoping to add a red line to the legend for these plots (at 4552), to show the capacity of a reservoir in the context of different annual reservoir inflow projections under different climate change scenarios, on a slide for discussion purposes (I don't need to annotate the red line). There are quite a few reservoirs, so if possible I'd like to do this all with R.

Thank you for any ideas.

[image]

Comment: This might be close to your problem, however not the exact solution - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13254441/add-a-horizontal-line-to-plot-and-legend-in-ggplot2

Comment: How about adding line to plot itself? This is more meaningful than adding line just to legend itself.

Comment: @JustCurious, I agree that works well for the example, but it wouldn't work for me for the lower facet plot, the one I really it need it for,  as it would be far too busy for my needs, with 82 years on each facet x13 scenarios =1066 red lines on an already busy page.  Having the red line on the legend quickly gets the point across of contrasting inflow magnitude with storage magnitude.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure how to add a custom line on gradient legend, but I do know how to add a custom tick label with custom color:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, color = y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_gradient(breaks = c(-2, 0, 1.7, 2),
                        labels = c(-2, 0, "1.7 (important)", 2)) +
  guides(color = guide_colorbar(barheight = 10,
                                label.theme = element_text(colour = c("black", "black", 
                                                                      "red", "black"), 
                                                           angle = 0,
                                                           size = 12)))
```

[image]

Notice that the "1.7" label overlaps the "2" label. You can either do something like the following:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, color = y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_gradient(breaks = c(-2, 0, 1.7, 2),
                        labels = c(-2, 0, "<-- 1.7 (important)", 2)) +
  guides(color = guide_colorbar(barheight = 10,
                                label.theme = element_text(colour = c("black", "black", 
                                                                      "red", "black"), 
                                                           angle = 0,
                                                           size = 12)))
```

[image]

or adjust the horizontal position of the "1.7" label:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, color = y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_gradient(breaks = c(-2, 0, 1.7, 2),
                        labels = c(-2, 0, "1.7 (important)", 2)) +
  guides(color = guide_colorbar(barheight = 10,
                                label.hjust = c(0, 0, 0.1, 0),
                                label.theme = element_text(colour = c("black", "black", 
                                                                      "red", "black"), 
                                                           angle = 0,
                                                           size = 12)))
```

[image]