# R - ggplot - add a line on the colorbar

Tags: r, ggplot2, colorbar

This is my **data** :

```
df <- data.frame(profile = rep(c(1,2), times = 1, each = 3), depth = c(100, 200, 300), value = c(1:3, 2:4))
```

I compute the **depth step** of each profile :

```
df$diff <- ave(df$depth, df$profile, FUN=function(z) c(z[1], diff(z)))
```

Finally I **plot** the results (one per profile)

For profile 1 :

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(profile), y = -diff, fill = value)) + geom_col() + 
  geom_rect(data = df[which(df$profile == 1),], aes(xmin = profile - 0.5, xmax = profile + 0.5, ymin = -max(df$depth), ymax = 0), size = 0.5, color = "red", fill = NA)
```

For profile 2 :

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(profile), y = -diff, fill = value)) + geom_col() + 
  geom_rect(data = df[which(df$profile == 2),], aes(xmin = profile - 0.5, xmax = profile + 0.5, ymin = -max(df$depth), ymax = 0), size = 0.5, color = "red", fill = NA)
```

And I get these figures

[image: Initial]

**My problem is** that I wish to add, on the colorbar, a line that represents the max value of the profile of interest. So my desired plots are those :

[image: Desired]

Thanks for help

Comment: Have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46638743/how-to-add-a-line-to-a-continuous-color-legend-but-not-the-plot?noredirect=1 seems like a duplicate

Comment: I agree. But in my case, with my script, I am not able to know the labels and the breaks of the colorbar