# How to add a vertical abline to the legend or write something on it in line plot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, legend, line-plot

I've added an verticle line at some point on x-axis (as shown in line plot of below Fig.) using *abline()* function in *R*, and I want to either put a legend for it or add some text over it (vertically on the abline).

So, is it possible to do this? If yes, then how I can do this?

[image: Sample Line plot]

Comment: Why did you tag with `ggplot2`?

Comment: @sindri_baldur This plot can generated in R using `ggplot2` library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `text` with the indicated arguments.  Alternately use the `legend` function as shown.

`abline` is classic graphics so it is assumed you want to use that plotting system but if you want ggplot2 see [Add a horizontal line to plot and legend in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13254441/add-a-horizontal-line-to-plot-and-legend-in-ggplot2/13254691#13254691) and make the obvious modifications to change the horizontal line to vertical.

```
x <- y <- 1:10; v <- 5  # input
plot(x, y)
abline(v = v, col = "red")
text("Vertical Line", x = v, y = max(y), srt = -90, pos = 4) # near top
text("Vertical Line", x = v, y = min(y), srt = 90, adj = c(0, -0.5)) # near bottom
legend("topleft", legend = "Vertical Line", pch = "|", col = "red")
```

[image: screenshot]