# Add custom tick mark to Y axis in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotations, aesthetics

I'd like to show the average for my dataset and add a tick mark on the Y-axis corresponding to this mean value - highlighted in red in the below image:

[image]

**Code**

```
plt <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = time, y = value)) + 
  geom_point(aes(fill = value),  size = 2, alpha = 0.8, shape = 21, stroke = 0.5, color = 'black') + 
  scale_color_gradientn(colors = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(4,name = 'OrRd')[-1], aesthetics = 'fill') +
  geom_hline(yintercept = dat[, mean(value, na.rm = T)], color = 'black', linetype = '11', size = 1.25) + 
  guides(fill = F)
```

I can use `scale_y_continuous()` to add a specific break point but it messes up the grid lines and I don't know how to customize that specific tick mark (if at all possible):

```
plt <- plt + 
         scale_y_continuous(breaks = round(c(seq(from = 0, to = dat[, max(value)], by = 10), dat[, mean(value)]), digits = 1) )
```

[image]

**Data**

Reduced dataset for reproducing the plot:

```
structure(list(time = structure(c(1607990400, 1607996400, 1608002400, 
1608008400, 1608014400, 1608020400, 1608026400, 1608032400, 1608038400, 
1608044400, 1608050400, 1608056400, 1608062400, 1608068400, 1608074400, 
1608080400, 1608086400, 1608092400, 1608098400, 1608104400, 1608110400, 
1608116400, 1608122400, 1608128400, 1608134400, 1608140400, 1608146400, 
1608152400, 1608158400, 1608164400, 1608170400, 1608176400, 1608182400, 
1608188400, 1608194400, 1608200400, 1608206400, 1608212400, 1608218400, 
1608224400, 1608230400, 1608236400, 1608242400, 1608248400, 1608254400, 
1608260400, 1608266400, 1608272400, 1608278400, 1608284400, 1608290400, 
1608296400, 1608302400, 1608308400, 1608314400, 1608320400, 1608326400, 
1608332400, 1608338400, 1608344400, 1608350400, 1608356400, 1608362400, 
1608368400, 1608374400, 1608380400, 1608386400, 1608392400, 1608398400, 
1608404400, 1608410400, 1608416400, 1608422400, 1608428400, 1608434400, 
1608440400, 1608446400, 1608452400, 1608458400, 1608464400, 1608470400, 
1608476400, 1608482400, 1608488400, 1608494400, 1608500400, 1608506400, 
1608512400, 1608518400, 1608524400, 1608530400, 1608536400, 1608542400, 
1608548400, 1608554400, 1608560400, 1608566400, 1608572400, 1608578400, 
1608584400, 1608590400, 1608596400, 1608602400, 1608608400, 1608614400, 
1608620400, 1608626400, 1608632400, 1608638400), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), value = c(3.87, 3.57, 4.12, 2.68, 
4.85447552447552, 0, 9.85, 2.9, 0.65010183299389, 2.55242704955998, 
2.94610169491525, 3.2225, 3.44, 3.2, 3.64666666666667, 3.6, 4.2236312849162, 
3.56285714285714, 2.99, 2.54, 2.34, 2.245, 2.05, 2.23666666666667, 
4.82, 13.81, 18.08, 4.0375, 3.96, 12.9723756906077, 23.87, 16.2053333333333, 
13.0836077705828, 10.91, 5.36238095238095, 2.62, 2.5375, 2.38, 
2.72, 2.345, 2.32909090909091, 3.90333333333333, 3.02166666666667, 
3.94833333333333, 3.83636363636364, 4.04117647058824, 4.22139146567718, 
5.57, 4.82, 3.59666666666667, 3.73873949579832, 2, 2.04, 2.57, 
3.00042016806723, 3.905, 5.65, 4.271589958159, 5.28, 7.15639534883721, 
5.45, 5.24295336787565, 3.11224489795918, 4.79, 2.6106976744186, 
2.25, 2.08264705882353, 2.25, 2.58666666666667, 3.18682008368201, 
3.24, 3.10375, 3.35833333333333, 4.39333333333333, 3.765, 7.71, 
5.16117647058824, 4.95588235294118, 2.44, 2.34666666666667, 2.345, 
2.375, 2.4275, 3.0975, 3.21666666666667, 4.13, 4.44663366336634, 
3.60877551020408, 3.83265033407572, 3.8625, 4.2675, 6.765, 2.688, 
2.43101242521859, 2.43561435803037, 2.30166666666667, 2.69, 3.18, 
5.04, 4.345, 4.86529411764706, 8.57, 6.2, 6.0032, 3.82, 5.03, 
7.02, 3.69716216216216, 3.00468438538206)), row.names = c(NA, 
-109L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Rather than mess with your axis, just add a reference line. You can either label it with a name or it's numeric value https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13254441/add-a-horizontal-line-to-plot-and-legend-in-ggplot2

Comment: Thanks, I have a reference line already but the client wanted to know if we can highlight the value on the axis as well. I guess I'll stick with `geom_text` and `geom_hline()` for now.

Answer (score 0):

Quick, dirty, and hacky:

```
plt + geom_text(aes(x = dat[, min(time, na.rm = T)], y = dat[, mean(value, na.rm = T)], label = round(dat[, mean(value, na.rm = T)],1)), color = 'red', hjust = 2) + coord_cartesian(clip = 'off')
```

Maybe it gets you somewhere.